# Suppressing fields in confirmation letter in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Can I suppress the printing of a field on the confirmation note? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

When you [set up confirmation emails](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/13/building-forms/confirmation-emails) in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), you can include fields in the custom confirmation message that you want to include, and then unselect the option to include all entry details:

[image]